# How create argument list in C++ during runtime to pass this to a template function(..., Ts &&... values) like in InsertOrUpdateMutationBuilder

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14, google-cloud-spanner

I want to program the google-cloud-spanner in C++.

The api-package I use is from https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp.
In the code https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/blob/main/google/cloud/spanner/samples/samples.cc from line 1677ff, one can see the method "EmplaceRow" from "InsertOrUpdateMutationBuilder", or the not very much simpler "MakeInsertOrUpdateMutation" from line 1739 till 1743.
Looking in
https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-spanner/latest/namespacegoogle_1_1cloud_1_1spanner.html
the example code for "EmplaceRow" and "MakeInsertOrUpdateMutation" can be seen.
More precise you can see the "EmplaceRow" example code on
https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-spanner/latest/namespacegoogle_1_1cloud_1_1spanner.html#a3451b640c4ee19df694fa0539047fcdc
and the "MakeInsertOrUpdateMutation" example code on
https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-spanner/latest/namespacegoogle_1_1cloud_1_1spanner.html#aced68ba9bc789f44693ad29962fc6ed6

**My Problem is:**
How can I create a variable (!) list of arguments to pass them into "EmplaceRow" or in "MakeInsertOrUpdateMutation" as "Ts &&... values".
And the "a variable list of arguments" means that this "list" (not a std::list) can be used in the mentioned manner as "Ts &&... values"-list.

Until now I did a lot of searching for a solution but I found no propper one:

1. Two template functions by using a std::tuple to expand its tuple elements to the "Ts &&... values"-list.
2. Two template functions by using a std::array to expand its array elements to the "Ts &&... values"-list.

Both solutions are "nice" but not useful!
I want process different tables with different number of columns during runtime but the size of std::tuple and std::array have to be fixed at compile-time (!).
Thus, creating a "Ts &&... values"-list during runtime can't be solved by std::tuple and std::array.

So ... how can I create from a std::vector, std::list, or other container-types, which could be created, resized and filled with "spanner::Value"-values, that "Ts &&... values"-list to pass it to "EmplaceRow" or "MakeInsertOrUpdateMutation".

Here is my code for expanding the std::tuple to an "Ts &&... values"-list:

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
int myInsrtOrUpdMutBldEmplaceRowBuild_Tup(confDataProc::processConfigData testA,
                                          Tuple const& tuple,
                                          std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
  namespace spanner = ::google::cloud::spanner;

  //std::cout << "the second 'myInsrtOrUpdMutBldEmplaceRowBuild_Tup'" << std::endl;
  auto client = GoClSp::MakeSampleClient(testA.getProjectID(), 
                                         testA.getInstanceID(),
                                         testA.getDatabaseID());
  auto commit = client.Commit(spanner::Mutations{
                              spanner::InsertOrUpdateMutationBuilder(
                                        testA.getTableName(),
                                        testA.getColumnNamesOfTable())
                                        .EmplaceRow(std::get<I>(tuple)...)
                                            .Build()});
  if (!commit)
  {
    throw std::runtime_error(commit.status().message());
  }

  return 0;
}
template <typename Tuple>
int myInsrtOrUpdMutBldEmplaceRowBuild_Tup(confDataProc::processConfigData testA,
                                          Tuple const& tuple)
{
  //std::cout << "the first 'myInsrtOrUpdMutBldEmplaceRowBuild_Tup'" << std::endl;

  int iRetVal = myInsrtOrUpdMutBldEmplaceRowBuild_Tup(testA, 
                        tuple,
                        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());

  return iRetVal;
}
```

This code works, but the big problem is that the size of the std::tuple must be known during compile time and can't be created during runtime with variable size/length. The size/length is in this context the number of columns of the processed table.

Maybe the solution is very obvious for other (better) programmers than me or maybe it is difficult. But anyway a helpful code snipped or a useful link is always welcome.

By the way:
In my experience this is very different to the 'classic' variadic arguments.
I have no possibility to change the behaviour of the method "EmplaceRow" or "MakeInsertOrUpdateMutation" - if I had I would like to change the "Ts &&... values"-list to a simpler "std::vectorspanner::Value values".

On the other hand:
If there is a other C++ function to insert or update table rows in a cloud-spanner table which I do not know, please inform me.
I "only" need a solution for insert or update a row of a table in C++, I do not insist on the way described above.

Comment: template functions are compiled and evaluated at compile time, so basically you can't use a container with dynamic size (which doesn't exist at all at compile time) to be expanded as arguments. You can pass the vector itself as argument (as reference or const reference). What you can do with template is to construct a template function which can manipulate different tables and rows, but with no way of using them as `std::list` or `std::vector`. They must be a compile time object like `std::tuple` or `std::array`

Comment: If I pass the vector itself this is only one argument and causes an error.
Is there a possibility to "expand" the vector to an argument list?
Maybe it is helpful that all arguments have the same data type "spanner::Value"?

Comment: IkarusDeveloper already explained why you cannot expand a vector into an argument list.

Comment: Yes, you are right and as I wrote the question I "feared" that there is no solution for std::vector but I hoped for another C++ container ... "there is always hope" :-). Now I will try the hint of Yakk - Adam Nevraumont.

Comment: My code of the accepted answer: `auto commit = client.Commit(spanner::Mutations{spanner::InsertOrUpdateMutationBuilder(testA.getTableName(),testA.getColumnNamesOfTable()).AddRow(spanValVect).Build()});`  This is the "key"-part ... rest like in the sample.cc, except the std::vector-creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `EmplaceRow` with [AddRow](https://googleapis.dev/cpp/google-cloud-spanner/master/classgoogle_1_1cloud_1_1spanner__internal_1_1v1_1_1WriteMutationBuilder.html#abed3897dfe15290b77e1c49555128641) and that should do the trick.

You cannot convert runtime arguments to template arguments in a practical way here.  (I could less than helpfully show you how, but trust me, bad plan here; I only don't say "impossible" because I dislike lying.)

I find google's C++ docs to require being willing and able to read the raw headers and sometimes source code.  Here, I found the class where `EmplaceRow` was defined and looked for either what it did, or an alternative method.

`Emplace` in C++ lingo means "perfect forward into storage"; usually there is an imperfect forwarding method nearby (like, `push_back` vs `emplace_back`) for when templates get in the way.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I found that "internal" function too, but no code snipped how to use it and I was not sure whether that function is a recommended function to use because it is "internal" ... ?

Comment: @modern_stonetime_programmer it is a public method.  Use away.  They would make it protected/private and/or comment in source if it was internal use only.  Lack of use in examples is because programmers are lazy and expect other C++ programmers to read source code.

Comment: Maybe lazy maybe unexperienced in understanding third party code - nevertheless thank you for your hint, I will try.

Comment: @modern oh it isn't you that is lazy.  It is google; they are lazy and don't document everything.  You have to look at their code to understand their APIs; often even the non headers!  Now, lazy is sometimes acceptable or even good.  But it definitely is here.

Comment: Yes, I understand. A big problem in that case is (was!) my usual practice that I was used, from "former times" ;-), that an "internal" or "non-official-code-example" function/method could change faster than the others and should be avoided ... so I have learned a lot by that problem and your answer: Everything can be used and is even expected (by the "producer") that you should use if it works.